# `TypeError` when using `cupy.nanstd` and `cupy.nanvar`

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

`cupy` raises `TypeError` while I'm running the following code on Windows 10.

```py
import cupy as cp
print(cp.nanstd(cp.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='float64')))
```

the error is shown as below:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-1194b91fc5af> in <module>
      1 import cupy as cp
      2 
----> 3 cp.nanstd(cp.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='float64'))

~\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\cupy\statistics\meanvar.py in nanstd(a, axis, dtype, out, ddof, keepdims)
    219     # TODO(okuta): check type
    220     return _statistics._nanstd(
--> 221         a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof, keepdims=keepdims)

cupy/core/_routines_statistics.pyx in cupy.core._routines_statistics._nanstd()

cupy/core/_routines_statistics.pyx in cupy.core._routines_statistics._nanstd()

cupy/core/_routines_statistics.pyx in cupy.core._routines_statistics._nanvar()

cupy/core/reduction.pxi in cupy.core._kernel.ReductionKernel.__call__()

cupy/util.pyx in cupy.util.memoize.decorator.ret()

cupy/core/_kernel.pyx in cupy.core._kernel._decide_params_type()

cupy/core/_kernel.pyx in cupy.core._kernel._decide_params_type_core()

TypeError: Type is mismatched. _count <class 'numpy.int32'> <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Here is some information about my device:

OS                    : Windows 10 64 bit

Python                : 3.7.5 (default, Oct 31 2019, 15:18:51) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

numpy Vesion          : 1.74.4

CuPy Version          : 7.0.0

CUDA Root             : C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0

CUDA Build Version    : 10000

CUDA Driver Version   : 10020

CUDA Runtime Version  : 10000

cuBLAS Version        : 10000

cuFFT Version         : 10000

cuRAND Version        : 10000

cuSOLVER Version      : (10, 0, 0)

cuSPARSE Version      : 10000

NVRTC Version         : (10, 0)

cuDNN Build Version   : 7605

cuDNN Version         : 7605

NCCL Build Version    : None

NCCL Runtime Version  : None

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
cp.nanstd(cp.asarray(np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='float64')))
```

alternatively

```
cp.nanstd(cp.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='float64'))
```

Comment: thanks for helping, but it raised the same error using `cp.nanstd(cp.ndarray(5, dtype='float64'))`

Comment: I suppose cause 5 isn't an array. try with [5] instead of 5.   Or if you are saying that it doesn't work at all, you could try to input a tuple instead of an array, cause it seems to be the type accepted by the method in the docs https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/latest/reference/generated/cupy.ndarray.html

Comment: Thanks, I changed to [5] but stilling not working. I also tried `dtype` as `float64`, `float32`, `float`, none of them works, while `int`, `int32`, `int64` works. However only take `int` as input is not quite acceptable.

Comment: better looked at docs. with this chain you create a numpy array -> convert in a cupy.ndarray -> calculate std on it.    (in google colab it makes me use cp.std and say doesn't find cp.nanstd, I don't know why, maybe newer version of the library...)

Comment: cp.ndarray takes as argument dimensions of the new array to create, so was creating a 1x2x3x4x5 matrix filled with random values. sorry, had misinterpreted in the beginning

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. It seems a bug of `cupy`. I raised an issue on their Github page. https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/2780

Comment: Except for the buggy TypeError. You're still sure you want to calculate standard deviation of a 5dimension random matrix? I don't get the point of doing it...

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion, I just want to make an array with 5 number to show the error. Surely I use the array with more meaningful value in practice.